# string to char to string to int

Tags: java

Basically, what this code does is getting a number in any length from the user and sends it back to the user in a digit per digit form plus the sum of all the digits on the given number(e.g. 1234= 1, 2, 3, 4. sum=10). However, I can't make it work on a negative number.

```
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);

    String num= s.nextLine();

    char arr[]= new char[num.length()];
    int numsarray[]= new int[num.length()];
    String number[]= new String[num.length()];
    int sum=0;

    for(int i=0; i<num.length();i++)
    {
        arr[i]=num.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(arr[i]);

        number[i]=Character.toString(arr[i]);

        numsarray[i]=Integer.parseInt(number[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<num.length();i++)
    {   
        sum+=numsarray[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Sum:"+sum);
```

Comment: And what is your problem, input, output, sum...?

Comment: Should it behave differently with a negative number? Is there a reason you aren't checking the character to see if it's not a number (-, space, period, etc.)?

Comment: it doesnt work on a negative number. i mean -1234 errors my code. it wont accept negative ones.

Comment: As an aside, the preferred way of declaring an array variable is to keep all the type information together, e.g. `char[] arr`.

Comment: -123 is valid entry but 1-23 is valid entry too ?

Comment: it should be. though we probably wont use it hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason you do not check first whether the number is less then 0 or not? You could then use abs to make it positive and run it through your function. Takes away the hassle to deal with the hyphen at arr[0]. Of course you should have some bool to store the sign :-)